# A chi indirizzo l'e-mail in questo caso specifico?

Tags: word-usage

Devo scrivere una e-mail alla segreteria di una scuola italiana, ma sono incerto riguardo al termine da usare nel preambolo che di solito (almeno nel mio caso) dice "Alla cortese attenzione di [omissione]". Ho il grande dubbio che potrei suonare *patronizing* (non conosco il termine in Italiano, chiedo perdono) riguardo al lavoro che la segreteria svolge, pur non volendo implicare questo in alcun modo.

Consigli?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - *Alla cortese attenzione di*.... non è affatto eccessiva o fuori luogo come espressione da usare in una mail.

- È un modo molto comune e cortese per rivolgersi all'attenzione di qualcuno in senso generico, senza usare il più formale *Egregio o Alla spettabile attenzione di...*

Esempio: [Alla cortese attenzione della Segreteria](https://www.docenti.unina.it/downloadPub.do?tipoFile=allegatoAvviso&idAvviso=1606&nomeFile=FRNRLF_1234191483157.doc&nome=modulo%20crediti%20aggiuntivi.doc)....

Comment: Grazie mille, Josh61!